# Uploading the file / documents via Amazon lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-lex

I am able to successfully

1) Create the chat bot using Amazon lex with custom intend and I tested in test bot
     2) I used the amazon javascript sdk : aws-sdk-2.41.0.min.js to access the amazon lex bot from my web application

As per the definition on Amazon document : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html

There are only two ways to send the data

```
postContent(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
       Sends user input (text or speech) to Amazon Lex.
postText(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
       Sends user input (text or SSML) to Amazon Lex.
```

But I am not able to find the feature to upload a file/document via amazon lex, Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lex as on date does not support sending attachments via postText or postContent methods. Handling attachments have to be custom developed using javascript.